# React use state array does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying call an API an get weather data for and i need to add every returned data to array state.but it does not work and it shows only last added data. Can someone please explain why it is happening and give me a solution

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';


const data = require('../src/data/Step1'); //Importing json file
const axios = require("axios");
function App() {

    //React Hook to save weather data
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState([]);

    //UseEffect to call getData function
    useEffect(() => {

        //call getData for each sending city code one by one
        data.List.map(city => getData(city.CityCode));

    }, []);

    //getData function
    async function getData(cityCode) {
        //Axios get request to http get request
        const response = await axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=' + cityCode + '&units=metric&appid=24e343673cb58392072a12e4705b1260');

        //adding each weather object to weather data Array
        setWeatherData([...weatherData,response.data.list[0]]);

    }
    if (weatherData.length > 1) {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    <div className="container mt-5">
                        {weatherData.map(x => (
                            <div className="row mt-2 ">
                                Id : {x.data.id} {" | "}
                                Name :{x.data.name} {" | "}
                                Description : {x.data.weather[0].description} {" | "}
                                Temperature : {x.data.main.temp}
                            </div>
                        ))}

                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Loading</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a setState does not happen synchronously so you are not assured the state will be updated next time you call it. Instead try the following

```
   async function getData(cityCode) {

        const response = await axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=' + cityCode + '&units=metric&appid=24e343673cb58392072a12e4705b1260');

        //adding each weather object to weather data Array
        setWeatherData(function (currentWeatherData) {
            return [...currentWeatherData, response.data.list[0]];
          });

    }
```

here is a repl sample [link](https://repl.it/join/bzmopayd-henride)

Comment: You are correct that setState is async but with hooks the effect callback has a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) of weatherData. This is why a linter would point this out but adding it would have the effect run too many times so the solution would be passing a callback to setWeatherData. So; your answer is correct but does not explain correctly why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the effect callback weatherData is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/). Maybe the following will work:

```
//using useCallback so the dependency of getData to the
// effect won't cause the effect to run other than when
// the component mounts
const getData = React.useCallback(async function getData(
  cityCode
) {
  const response = await axios.get(
    'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=' +
      cityCode +
      '&units=metric&appid=24e343673cb58392072a12e4705b1260'
  );
  setWeatherData((weatherData) => [
    //using callback so weatherData is not a dependency
    ...weatherData,
    response.data.list[0],
  ]);
},
[]);
useEffect(() => {
  //if you don't use the result of a map then use forEach instead
  data.List.forEach((city) => getData(city.CityCode));
}, [getData]);
```

You can pass a callback to the state setter `setWeatherData` that receives the current state and returns the new state.